# How to extract data from angular http.get.subscribe

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

I'm using the [Ionic 2 Calendar](https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar) to display class times that have been subscribed to as **json** from a remote server. I am trying to extract the response from my subscription and put it into an array, but when putting the data out to console.log, I get "undefined".

The code is as follows:

```
export class Calendar {
    eventSource;
    viewTitle;

    constructor(private navController:NavController, private httpService:HttpService) {
        var classes = [];
        this.httpService.getCalendarConfig()
            .subscribe(res => classes => res);

        console.log(classes);
    }
```

Note, if I change .subscribe to:

```
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

It displays the JSON as it should in the console.

**Edit**: the httpService class looks as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    endpointUrl:string = '<address>';

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getCalendarConfig() {
        return this.http.get(this.endpointUrl + 'calendar.json')
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? '${error.status} - ${error.statusText}' : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Because you are considering that `classes` value to be applicable as soon as you make a call to service. But that wouldn't work with the way async calls works. They will always provide there output as soon as they `ajax` completes.

You will get the `classes` object inside success of the subscription of `this.httpService.getCalendarConfig()`

```
var classes = [];
this.httpService.getCalendarConfig()
    .subscribe(res => {
      classes => res;
      console.log(classes);
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Pankaj Parkar, thank you, that has improved the situation, as it no longer says "undefined". But now the console says: Array [ ]. Have I assigned to the wrong data type?

Comment: Could you please open that array.. you will get elements in it

Comment: Hi @Pankaj sorry for the delay! How do you open the array?

Comment: @JohnSmith please could you provide a plunkr?

Comment: I don't have a plunkr, but I've updated the post to show the full code. Thank you!